# groupby and unstack from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame from tips.csv
i want grouping data by day and sex like this :

[image]

but my result like this :

[image]

and this my code

```
df.groupby(['day','sex'])['tip'].sum().unstack('sex').reset_index()
```

Any ideas and suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Do you mean that you need the order of days to stay the same?

Comment: yes and delete column sex

Comment: You must provide the input in a reproducible format

Answer (score 0):

don use `reset_index`

```
df.groupby(['day','sex'])['tip'].sum().unstack('sex')
```

If this does not solve problem, make a simple example and upload it as text instead of image.

Comment: make a simple example data and upload it as text or code instead of image.